# Session data duplicate storage for multiple hits

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, session, servlets

I can store the session data in database. But when the user clicks to store the session data again, the data is stored in database with new id generated. I have to ensure that the session data once stored in database should not be stored again. I am using servlets, jsp and hibernate. Using hibernate i am storing the list with saveOrUpdateAll method in hibernate.

Comment: Add details about the entities add code that is causing the issue.

Comment: looks like you id generation strategy is auto increment, cant confirm though, unless you paste your entities and other details here.

Comment: Id generation stratergy is autoincrement only. Shopping cart details are stored in list and i can able to store the list in database using saveOrUpdateAll method from hibernate which takes collections as parameter. But problem is that , as the data is in session and the session time out i set is 30 min, so when the user re-submits the page, the session data is stored again in database with different id. How to make sure that the data thats stored from session should not be re-inserted in database again